# Effective way to append strings separated with comma [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin

I was wondering if there is an **effective way of separating different strings with comma as the separator**?

In `Java8` there was `StringUtils.join(java.lang.Iterable,char)`.

For `Kotlin` I only found `joinToString`, which converts from array/list to string. As I understand, `joinToString` converts whole list/array. What if I want to convert a few items from array to comma separated string not all of them? How would one do that? Is there something short and elegant from `Kotlin` (obviously, I can make my own function for this, but I was just wondering).

```
list.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
   if (item.isGreen) {
       ...        
   }
}
```

Comment: use StringJoiner

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
val greenString = list.filter(ItemClass::isGreen).joinToString()
```

Here, *ItemClass* is the type of your item which defines the isGreen function or property. `ItemClass::isGreen` is a reference to this method/property.

You could also use a lambda for the same effect (see other answer).

---

**Edit**: You can specify how the object should be represented as a String in the joinToString function with the transform argument.
Because this is the last parameter it can be given outside of the regular parentheses:

```
list.filter(ItemClass::isGreen).joinToString() { it.content.text }
```

You could even leave off the parentheses all together now but they may be used for other arguments.
You can not use the reference style (::) here because it is a complex expression and not a direct reference to a specific method or property.

Comment: And what if my item object would consist of two seperate objects?
`ItemClass::isGreen` and `itemClass::content` and I would like to filter by `ItemClass::isGreen` just as you wrote, but only joinToString `itemClass::content.name`

Comment: [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) has a `transform` parameter that takes a lambda of type `(T) -> String`, so you can pass `{ it.content.name }` to it.

Comment: @zsmb13 Can you write down a practical example, please?

Comment: You can call it as either `list.joinToString(transform = { it.content.name })` with a named parameter, or as `list.joinToString { it.content.name }`, since the lambda is the last parameter of the function.

Answer (score 18):

For this example you can do this:

```
list
    .filter { it.isGreen }
    .joinToString()
```

Comment: If somebody looks for another separator, use `joinToString(separator = "\n")`.

Comment: does the job, but by default joinToString seems to add an additional space after comma, so had to be specific with the separator => joinToString(separator = ",")

Comment: Great answer! In case you needed a slight variation of above as we did: `list.filter {it.isVibgyor}.map{color -> "'$color'"}.joinToString(",") will produce: 'violet','indigo','green' `

Comment: @CoolMind Thanks, I did not need the space between commas, so I used `list.joinToString(separator = ",", transform = { it.myReqiredObject.toString()})`

Answer (score 0):

***Best way to append strings separated with comma***

```
  val tmp: List<String?> = mList.filter{ it -> it!!.isNotEmpty() }
  txt_addresss.text = tmp.joinToString()
```

In your case

```
val tmp: List<Item?> = list.filter{ it -> it!!.isGreen }
txt_addresss.text = tmp.joinToString()
```